# MOSS 2007 Navigation Options/Settings

Tags: sharepoint, moss2007enterprisesearch

I have a subsite that I have changed the "global navigation" setting to

```
"Display the navigation items below the current site"
```

This works correctly. I then need to "add a link" this is a link back to the root web site basically "/Pages/Default.asp"

I click OK and there are no errors, but the link does not get displayed and when I go back the the navigation settings the link is no longer there.

This works just fine in the root web navigation

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research,  I found a bug in our custom minimal publishing site definition onet.xml that was causing the issue. The  Element had a typo in it

```
<NavBars>
   <narbar Name="SharePointTop Navbar" ID="1002" />
<NavBars>
```

"narbar" should be "navbar". When I fixed it, any new sub-sites created did not have this issue. I was now able sort/edit the navigation items for those new sub-sites.

In order to fix the already created sub-sites, I had to update the NavNodes table in my content db. I found a forum post hat help me:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/fb22476c-9145-476b-a1c9-7fe85aa12272

I had to modify the t-sql statement in the above forum post to add "Quick Launch" rows for each sub-site in the NavNodes table. The next time a user tries to modify the navigation sorting/editing for a sub-site, the changes will be saved.

Answer (score 2):

[This solution](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/fb22476c-9145-476b-a1c9-7fe85aa12272) worked for me:

```
INSERT INTO 
NavNodes 

([SiteId] ,
[WebId] ,
[Eid] ,
[EidParent] ,
[NumChildren] ,
[RankChild] ,
[ElementType] ,
[Url] ,
[DocId] ,
[Name] ,
[DateLastModified] ,
[NodeMetainfo] , [NonNavPage] ,[NavSequence] ,[ChildOfSequence])

SELECT DISTINCT
SiteId, WebId ,1002 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,'' ,NULL ,'SharePoint Top Navbar' ,getdate() ,NULL ,0 ,1 ,0 
FROM NavNodes 
WHERE WebId NOT IN (
  SELECT WebId 
  FROM NavNodes
  WHERE Eid = 1002)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. I just tested your scenario and it worked for me. I added a 'David Button' link under the Global Navigation top-level folder after checking the *Display the navigation items below the current site* setting. The link appears and once I return to the Navigation Settings, it is still there.

Maybe you have cache enabled?

Answer (score 0):

If you have caching turned on you may need to flush this (checking the security settings of each link is an expensive operation).

The link below tells you how to:
- Configure the object cache
- Flush the object cache or the disk-based cache

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101577831033.aspx